# Ubuntu desktop script to open terminal, navigate to a folder and run compass watch

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, desktop

I have tried to search for a simple answer for running a simple script (myscript.sh) from the Ubuntu (13) desktop that would open the terminal, navigate to a folder (/var/www/myproject) and then run the "compass watch" command (and then stay open). First I thought this would be very simple to accomplish, but after several fails and searches, this particular task/script seems overwhelmingly hard to get to work.

To do this manually is not a big task:

- Open terminal
- navigate "cd /var/www/myproject"
- run "compass watch"

I thought this would be a walk in the park (although I am quite new to terminal and scripting), but through the searches I got some weird desktop launcher answers and complicated bash scripting functions solutions for sub-shell work-a-rounds. My question is, can this be done with one single (simple) file that is launched from the desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you make a shell script (`.sh` file, don't forget to make it executable) or you make a desktop file (`.desktop`).  Either of those can be double-clicked, although the former might bring up a dialog asking whether you want to execute it (can be configured, but only per user, IIRC).

**`myscript.desktop`**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=bash -c 'cd /var/www/myproject && compass watch'
Name=myscript
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

(Note the `Terminal=true` part.)

**`myscript.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -e 'cd /var/www/myproject && compass watch'
```

(Assuming you want to use GNOME Terminal.)

Of course, there are numerous other options.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get well where is your problem ...
If you want to run a script like that (double clic) you should first make it executable:

```
chmod u+x myscript.sh
```

Then you just have to place a link to this script on your desktop (or the script itself if you want ...)
When double-clicking it, you will have the possibility to run it in a terminal.

Then put whatever you want in your script ( the  *navigate "cd /var/www/myproject" , run "compass watch"* part) and end the script (myScript.sh) file with `$SHELL` to keep the terminal open after the script execution (: